# Telerik RadGrid SelectedItem is not pointing to the actual selected item when filter is applied

Tags: radgrid

```
Grid.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Grid_SelectedIndexChanged);

void Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataItem item = Grid.SelectedItems[0].DataItem;
}
```

The selecteditem is good when no filter is applied. But when filter is applied, the grid displays the filtered items only, which is right. But when the item is selected it's bringing in the item from the full list instead of the filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The following line did the trick.

```
Grid.EnableViewState = false;
```